# Maximization of a weighted average

Tags: optimization

Suppose that $f$ is a weighted average of the functions $g_i$, $$f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^N \lambda_i \cdot g_i(x)$$ (where each $\lambda_i >0$).  Under what conditions is the maximum value of $f$ a weighted average of the maximum values of the $g_i$?  $$ \max_x f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^N \lambda_i \cdot \max_x g_i(x)$$

Comment: Are the $\lambda_i$ non-negative?

Comment: Yes.  I've updated the question.

Comment: @joriki why is it not sufficient? Is that easy to see?

Comment: @joriki yes, I understand that that would have to be the explanation, but I just don’t see it. I’ll just give it more thought. Thanks.

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist: Sorry, it was I who was confused :-) I deleted the comment.

Comment: @JDG22: Are you looking for sufficient or necessary conditions, or both?

Comment: @joriki yes, I was thinking convexity of the max operator would be enough to show that the condition you stated was sufficient. I doubt it is necessary, however.

Comment: Unless all $g_i(x)$ have the maximum at the same $x$ it is hard to see if it is true.